# Virtual machine-type-software where you can install other software and test it

Tags: sandbox

I remember some software which was like a virtual PC except you didn't need to install an OS, it used the real one. You installed software on it and could use the software in the "virtual PC" and it wouldn't do anything to your "real" computer then if you liked the software you could just transfer it (not reinstall it).

But I have no idea what the name of it was and searching for virtual PC in google doesn't help as its all just MS and Virtualbox. Does anyone know of this software?

Comment: What you describe sounds exactly like virtualbox..=/

Comment: but Virtual box you have to install an OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was it [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com/)?

Comment: Damn, beaten to it.

Comment: no but its the same thing as that. I think it had like a box at the top of the screen and you selected the "virtual pc"s through that.

Comment: Sandboxie is really good - but it's the only thing of it's kind I know of. if you find what you're looking for, I'd love to hear about it - it sounds great :)

Comment: Yes sandboxie looks great but its only 32-bit, and in response to 64-bit version possible was "Not available, and not planned."

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing I can think of is "Containers", which are somewhere between a full virtual machine and ... well, and not having a full virtual machine.

On linuz, [OpenVZ](http://wiki.openvz.org/Main_Page) is probably the most popular container system.

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't it [**GoBack**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goback) from Norton (or Adaptec or Symantec or others...) ? It's obsolete now, since Vista's release.

Another program exists with the same kind of features: [**Rollback Rx**](http://www.horizondatasys.com/169614.ihtml)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, are you thinking of [MojoPac](http://www.mojopac.com/)?